# Why this code is returning a None value?

Tags: python, function, input, chatbot

I have written this very simple code that should respond to specific user inputs. I know I'm doing something wrong, but I don't know what is it. When I type a word or leave blank I get the response "None". Thank you in advance :)
here is my code:

```
import random
# Sentences we'll respond with if the user greeted us

GREETING_KEYWORDS = ("hello", "hi", "greetings", "sup", "whats up", "You")
GREETING_RESPONSES = ["sup buddy", "Hola", "Halo", "Hi back?"]


def check_for_greeting(sentence):
  """If any of the words in the user's input was a greeting, return a greeting response"""
   if sentence is not None:
       for word in sentence:
           if word.lower() in GREETING_KEYWORDS:
               return random.choice(GREETING_RESPONSES)
           else:
               pass
   elif sentence is None:
       return "You got to say something if you want me to do the same."
   else:
       return "Something is wrong..."


def chat_input():
    x = input("")
    print(check_for_greeting(x))

# Run
print("chat with me...")
chat_input()
```

Comment: Although this doesn't really have much to do with the question itself, I suggest turning sentence into a list of  `' '.join(sentence)` and checking for the existence of the greeting word inside the sentence using `len([i for i in GREETING_KEYWORDS if i in sentence]) > 0`

Comment: what if I didn't know what the user entered, if they input "hello" or "good bye". Should I just create another list and loop through it when the list "GREETING KEYWORDS" has no match ? Thank you man, your feedback is useful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
for word in sentence:
    if word.lower() in GREETING_KEYWORDS:
        return random.choice(GREETING_RESPONSES)
    else:
        pass
```

What if none of the words is in `GREETING_KEYWORDS`? What is returned then? There is no explicit `return` statement for when that happens, so the answer is: `None` is returned.

You can fix that by returning a default response if the `for` loop completes without finding a greeting.

```
for word in sentence:
    if word.lower() in GREETING_KEYWORDS:
        return random.choice(GREETING_RESPONSES)
return "default response"
```

The next problem is that `for word in sentence` iterates over each *letter* of the sentence, not each *word*. To iterate over words, split the sentence apart:

```
for word in sentence.split():
    if word.lower() in GREETING_KEYWORDS:
        return random.choice(GREETING_RESPONSES)
return "default response"
```

Next, I see that you want to detect a two-word greeting: `whats up`. That's not going to work since splitting the sentence into words means you can only check for one-word greetings. I'd suggest inverting the logic: loop over all the possible greetings and see if they're in the sentence. (Notice that now you *don't* want to split the sentence into words.)

```
for greeting in GREETING_KEYWORDS:
    if greeting in sentence:
        return random.choice(GREETING_RESPONSES)
return "default response"
```

Finally, this is a little more advanced, but you could use a generator expression plus `any()` to simplify the check down to a simple if/else.

```
if any(greeting in sentence for greeting in GREETING_KEYWORDS):
    return random.choice(GREETING_RESPONSES)
else:
    return "default response"
```

I like this because it reads more like plain English.

Comment: `return next((random.choice(GREETING_RESPONSES) for greeting in GREETING_KEYWORDS if greeting in sentence)), 'default')`

Comment: Only disadvantage is substrings, like `'hi'` is in `'this'`